# Make compiler interpret some chosen symbol (say, a comma) as a line breaking hint within an environment?

Tags: line-breaking

Here's a minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

% some text
\parbox{\linewidth}{a short phrase, followed by another}

\parbox{\linewidth}{this is also a short one, but it is followed by this very long one which will need a line break, as I have designed it to need a line break, since I am trying to create a MnWE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, this is not always something one would want to do, but I'd like to somehow like to give LaTeX a hint that if it needs to break lines, it should preferentially break them after commas (in general, it could be some other symbol), thus it would create output like:

[image]

Since it's not something one would always like to do, we probably want to wrap the text we would like to be formatted in this way within an environment that takes as an argument the symbol that should be used as a line breaking hint.

How could this be done?

Comment: One can use \sloppy or \raggedright instead of \fussy (default) to reduce hypehnation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept: the comma is defined to produce a standard comma followed by `\linebreak[2]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment{specialcomma}
 {\begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\string,\linebreak[2]}%
  \catcode`,=\active\par}
 {\par}

\begin{document}


this is also a short one, but it is followed by this very 
long one which, will need a line break, as I have designed 
it to need a line break, since I am trying to create a MnWE

\begin{specialcomma}
this is also a short one, but it is followed by this very 
long one which, will need a line break, as I have designed 
it to need a line break, since I am trying to create a MnWE
\end{specialcomma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can "suggest" make a line break at any point (weakly with `\linebreak[1]`  or  strongly with `\linebreak[3]`) or force it (`\linebreak[4]` or simply `\linebreak`). However, as far you force the line breaks, as far the interword spaces will be worse. When is not a mandatory command, usually will be ignored because this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\extraword{xxxxxx}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\linewidth}{a short phrase,\linebreak[2]  % this will be ignored 
followed by another}

\parbox{\linewidth}{
this is also a short one,  \linebreak  % this work always, but you want this?
but it is followed by this  long one which will need line break \extraword, 
% \linebreak[1]  will work with a \extraword as long as  'xxxxxx'.  
% \linebreak[2]  will work with a \extraword of 4-5  characters.
% \linebreak[3]  will work  with a \extraword of 1-3 characters (no 0).
% \linebreak[4]  will work always (as without the optional argument)
\linebreak[1]
as I have designed it to need a line break, 
\linebreak[3] % This will never be enough here ...
since I am trying to create a MnWE.}

\end{document}
```

Moreover, every  minimal changes in the content or the format will make useless or detrimental this type of fixes. I suggest be careful with the hyphenation and use `microtype` instead, no matter where the commas ended.

Comment: What is `microtype`? Also, in the example you have provided, one has to constantly specify where they might want a line break. I just want a comma, in general, to be interpreted as a good place to break a line.

Comment: By the way, I have re-written my question and its title because I realized that it was confusing and not really getting at what I wanted. Do you think it speaks more clearly to what I am looking for?

Comment: @user89  Then you should accept the new answer of egreg. To add the line break automatically, the comma must be an active character.  But automatically or not, this always will produce a bad spacing. The `microtype` package instead try to produce better interword spaces and more. There a lot of examples about in this site. Prudently used will produce a better typography.  It is not a solution to what you ask, but to what you (should) want. `:)`